# Command-line interface design with base options and subcommands

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I'm trying to develop a command line interface for a tool I'm writing. I'm tossing up between an interface similar to Fabric's `fab` tool and one like svn's command line tool.

`fab`'s usage message:

```
Usage: fab [options] <command>[:arg1,arg2=val2,host=foo,hosts='h1;h2',...] ...
```

`svn`'s usage message:

```
usage: svn <subcommand> [options] [args]
```

Note that `svn` also supports two options `--version` and `--quiet` (at least the one I'm using).

My questions are:

1. Is fab's cli (with multiple commands, each of which can have arguments) design common among command-line tools? To me, the svn tool's cli seems more commonly used (not sure though).
2. Would it be straightforward implementing fab's cli using [plac](http://plac.googlecode.com/hg/doc/plac.html)(or argparse)?
3. If I do decide to go with svn's cli, can be this be implemented using plac? I like plac, though I haven't been able to figure out how to add options to the tool directly, instead of the subcommands. It can definitely be implemented using [argparse](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/argparse-vs-optparse.html#sub-commands).

P.S.: The only reason fab's cli appeals to me is that one can accomplish multiple tasks in one step, however ease of implementation is my main concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. subversion's way is more standard.
2. Probably not.
3. You can cut butter with a hand axe.

If you want to simplify documentation and usage, go with SVN's way. I can see why fab's way seems appealing, it's logical for a programmer. But it's actually complicated and messed up for users.

Plac looks cool, but you need to install it. Your users too.

I like to follow a simple rule when it comes to software engineering:
Keep it simple and standard, use bleeding edge technologies when you really **need** it.
Retro-compatibility should be achieved when possible.

However, you're just fooling around and don't plan on distributing your work, then go on, flab's way and using flac ;).